# Does the custom reject message entered when rejecting a test in the Suggested Edits Review queue go somewhere?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, rejected-edits

Every once in a while when reviewing Suggested Edits, the system creates a fake edit with nonsense text.

When rejecting the fake edit, I usually enter a custom reject message, e.g.

> Ah, my old nemesis, finally we meet again for the first time for the 10th time!
>
> Ha, thought you'd get me this time, did you?
>
> Almost thought "recreational downloads" was an actual edit, good one, chap!

These are obviously purely for my own amusement, but I was wondering if these messages go somewhere (like a statistic or a log or whatever), or if I am basically just talking to the void.

Comment: I would have expected it in the [comment](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/860107) on reviewtaskresults but for audits this doesn't seem to be populated.

Comment: Maybe they go to an staff only chat room so they can have a chuckle over the best admissions ...

Comment: Just hope the void doesn't talk back.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: No, that only happens on meta.